# Sharepoint2010 Programmaticaly assign the prefix for the Document ID Service

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm creating a new site collection where the document ID service should be activated. How can i programmatically set the prefix for the document ID service inside the new site collection?

[EDIT]
This seems to be the solution.

```
            using (SPSite rootSite = new SPSite(URL + "sites/123021")) {
            rootSite.Features.Add(new Guid("b50e3104-6812-424f-a011-cc90e6327318"));
            using (SPWeb web = rootSite.OpenWeb(String.Empty, true)){
                web.Properties["docid_settings_ui"] = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><DocIdUiSettings xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><Prefix>88888</Prefix><AssignmentEnabled>true</AssignmentEnabled></DocIdUiSettings>";
                web.AllProperties["docid_settings_ui"] = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><DocIdUiSettings xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><Prefix>88888</Prefix><AssignmentEnabled>true</AssignmentEnabled></DocIdUiSettings>"; 
                web.Update();
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Marco

Answer (score 1):

You can change the prefix used by the document id service by setting the docid_msft_hier_siteprefix property of the RootWeb of the site collection (change it in both the Properties and AllProperties property bags.

Toby

Answer (score 0):

I verified the "Answer" for SharePoint 2013, it does set the prefix in the Document ID settings page. But the timer jobs for Document ID service wont apply the new prefix. you should try this

```html
// Set document id service prefix
DocumentId.SetDefaultProvider(rootSite);
DocumentId.EnableAssignment(rootSite, "MYPREFIX", true, true, true, false);
```

for more details information please see my blog post on this issue.
http://blogs.perficient.com/multi-shoring/blog/2015/01/13/set-document-id-prefix-programmatically-in-sharepoint-2013/